# Table Sub Query in LINQ

Tags: entity-framework, linq

How can I write this Query in LINQ?

I am applying sub-query to Employee table because I want all qualification of only Male employees.

```
Select emp.Name, qual.Name, qual.Description 
from Qualification qual 
INNER JOIN ( Select emp.QualId from Employee emp where emp.Gender='Male') emp
ON qual.Id = emp.QualId
```

Comment: What is you attempt? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause

Comment: SO cannot be used as a free coding service. What have you done so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: may be this helps you `from qual in Qualification
           join emp in Employee on qual.ID equals emp.QualId
     where emp.Gender='Male'
           select new { emp.Name, qual.Name, qual.Description  }`

Answer (score 0):

So you have two classes Employee and Qualification. There is a one-to-many relation between Employee and Qualification

- Every Qualifcation has zero or more Employees
- Every Employee has exactly one Qualification

If you follow the [default entity framework one-to-many configuration](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) you'll have classes like

```
class Qualification
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}

    // a Qualification has zero or more Employees
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees {get; set;}
}
class Employee
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Gender {get; set;}

    // Every Employee has exactly one Qualification using foreign key
    public int QualificationId {get; set;}
    public virtual Qualification Qualification {get; set;}
 }
```

This is all Entity Framework needs to know to configure the one-to-many relationship. If you have different property names you'll have attributes or fluent API to inform Entity Framework about their functionality.

Now back to your query: you want the names of all Male employees together with the Name and Description of his Qualification

```
var result = dbContext.Employee
    .Where(employee => employee.Gender == "Male")
    .Select(employee => new
    {
        EmployeeName = employee.Name,
        QualificationName = employee.Qualification.Name,
        QualificationDescription = employee.Qualification.Description,
    });
```

Entity framework will create the correct join for this.